# Matcher find a pattern but throw No match available on `start` method

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the a sub string of the text after the regex, therefore I check if it exist with `find`, then I try to get `start` / `end` / `group` but `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available` is thrown.

```
String text = "Hello bob, remind me to do a lot of things today";
pattern = Pattern.compile("remind.*.to.");
// Looking for "remind <anyWord> to "
if (pattern.matcher(text).find())
{
    pattern.matcher(text).group();
}
```

The regex is found, therefore I in the condition, but `start()` (/any other int method) throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that you're using `pattern.matcher(text)` again and that creates another `Matcher` instance and when you call `start()` on a new instance it throws exception since `find` or `matches` or `lookingAt` has not been called before.

You may use it like this:

```
String text = "Hello bob, remind me to do a lot of things today";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("remind.*\\hto\\h");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text); // create it only once
// Looking for "remind <anyWord> to "
if (m.find()) {
    System.err.println( "Start: " + m.start() + ", match: " + m.group() );
}
```

Also note changes in your regex. `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace whereas `.to.` will match any character before and after `to` hence your regex will match:

```
"remind me to do a lot of things tod"
```

instead of intended:

```
"remind me to do "
```

Comment: Thank you very much + for the explantion + regex fix. learn a lot of new stuff in one answer :)

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks for sharing. Really new learning for me

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `pattern.matcher(text)` one time, to do this, just create a Matcher like so:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String result = matcher.group();
    //output: "remind me to do a lot of things tod"
}
```